# how to create a table from a set of arrays with dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, data-science

in the data, column df['comments'] consists of 88107 rows with arrays with dictionaries

```
`
[{'text': "It will be curious to see where this heads in the long run.  CBS is on a tear but will it fit their image, will they try and establish control, overall agenda.  I've enjoyed last.fm for many years supporting through paypal donations each time I expire...it'll be interesting.",
  'score': 0},
 {'text': "Does this mean that there's now a big-name company who will fight for the repeal of the recent streaming-music royalty hike?",
  'score': 1},
 {'text': 'Also on BBC News:  http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/low/technology/6701863.stm .Nice to see a London-based co. hit the headlines.',
  'score': 2},
 {'text': "I don't understand what they do that is worth $70M a year. ",
  'score': 3},
 {'text': 'sold out too cheaply. given their leadership position, they should have ask for at least $500m',
  'score': 4}]
`
```

how to make one big table with columns 'text' and 'score'

```
`l=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df['comments'][0])+1):
    n1=pd.DataFrame(data=df['comments'][i])
    l=pd.concat([l, n1], axis=0)`
```

I was able to make a table from one array, but I can't open all 88000
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtKf6.png)

Comment: Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html): `pd.json_normalize(df['comments'])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
>>> pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df['comments'])], axis=1)

                                            comments                                               text  score
0  {'text': 'It will be curious to see where this...  It will be curious to see where this heads in ...      0
1  {'text': 'Does this mean that there's now a bi...  Does this mean that there's now a big-name com...      1
2  {'text': 'Also on BBC News:  http://news.bbc.c...  Also on BBC News:  http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/low...      2
3  {'text': 'I don't understand what they do that...  I don't understand what they do that is worth ...      3
4  {'text': 'sold out too cheaply. given their le...  sold out too cheaply. given their leadership p...      4
```

Or use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df['comments'].tolist())], axis=1)
                                            comments                                               text  score
0  {'text': 'It will be curious to see where this...  It will be curious to see where this heads in ...      0
1  {'text': 'Does this mean that there's now a bi...  Does this mean that there's now a big-name com...      1
2  {'text': 'Also on BBC News:  http://news.bbc.c...  Also on BBC News:  http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/low...      2
3  {'text': 'I don't understand what they do that...  I don't understand what they do that is worth ...      3
4  {'text': 'sold out too cheaply. given their le...  sold out too cheaply. given their leadership p...      4
```

If you want to remove `comments` column, just replace `df['comments']` by `df.pop('comments')` like:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df.pop('comments'))], axis=1)
```

Comment: Yop, if OP need your solution it is dupe. But from picture data are different like in both another answers.

Answer (score 1):

If for each value of `comments` is list of dictionaries, need flatten them with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [{'text': "It will be curious to see where this heads in the long run.  CBS is on a tear but will it fit their image, will they try and establish control, overall agenda.  I've enjoyed last.fm for many years supporting through paypal donations each time I expire...it'll be interesting.",
  'score': 0},
 {'text': "Does this mean that there's now a big-name company who will fight for the repeal of the recent streaming-music royalty hike?",
  'score': 1},
 {'text': 'Also on BBC News:  http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/low/technology/6701863.stm .Nice to see a London-based co. hit the headlines.',
  'score': 2},
 {'text': "I don't understand what they do that is worth $70M a year. ",
  'score': 3},
 {'text': 'sold out too cheaply. given their leadership position, they should have ask for at least $500m',
  'score': 4}]

df = pd.DataFrame({'comments':[ L, L, L]})
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame([y for x in df['comments'] for y in x])
print (df)
                                                 text  score
0   It will be curious to see where this heads in ...      0
1   Does this mean that there's now a big-name com...      1
2   Also on BBC News:  http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/low...      2
3   I don't understand what they do that is worth ...      3
4   sold out too cheaply. given their leadership p...      4
5   It will be curious to see where this heads in ...      0
6   Does this mean that there's now a big-name com...      1
7   Also on BBC News:  http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/low...      2
8   I don't understand what they do that is worth ...      3
9   sold out too cheaply. given their leadership p...      4
10  It will be curious to see where this heads in ...      0
11  Does this mean that there's now a big-name com...      1
12  Also on BBC News:  http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/low...      2
13  I don't understand what they do that is worth ...      3
14  sold out too cheaply. given their leadership p...      4
```

Comment: It's probably a dupe, no?

Comment: @Corralien - Added data to answer what I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comperhension:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'comments': [
        [{'text': 'comment 1', 'score': 1}, {'text': 'comment 2', 'score': 2}],
        [{'text': 'comment 3', 'score': 3}],
        [{'text': 'comment 4', 'score': 4}, {'text': 'comment 5', 'score': 5}, {'text': 'comment 6', 'score': 6}]
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

comments_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(c) for c in df['comments']], ignore_index=True)

result_df = pd.merge(df.drop(columns=['comments']), comments_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(result_df)
```

Output:

```
  id       text  score
0   1  comment 1      1
1   2  comment 2      2
2   3  comment 3      3
```